# Deducing signature of (non-)templated types

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I'm relatively new to writing template metaprogramming, it's probably the reason I couldn't find a solution to this problem. The problem is this: I'm developing a mathematics library, with so many functions like determining the primeness of an integer or std::initializer_list, changing integers to roman numerals among many other things. The bottleneck started when I tried to implement a generic function that returns the result of a function call such that:

```
apply( foo, 1 ) === foo( 1 );
```

For template functions, it wouldn't make any sense if it's written like so:

```
apply( foo<int, int, int...>, 1, 2, 3... ); //Case 1
apply<int, int, double...>( foo, 1, 2, 3...) // Case 2
//OR whichever flavours the (closure object or ) callable has.
```

So I decided to write **apply** such that it does not have to look like the immediate ugly code above( **case 2** to be precise). I landed [here](http://pastebin.com/GnUFnhNe) at first and then I thought that was incorrect, then I rewrote it again [here](http://pastebin.com/Ri1f1Cs5).

Right now, I'm out of ideas and I know well I could make use of **std::function** in **apply** but I don't wanna use it unless there's no other way. Please don't get me wrong, I'm not saying std::function is not applicable here, I'm just saying I will, if and only if I don't have any other option.

NOTE: The math library is a side project I use to teach my college mates how C++ does things, therefore I make lesser use of some advanced concepts.

Comment: Do you expect it to work for function objects, or only functions? Does it need to handle overloaded names?

Comment: Right now, the goal is to make it work on function pointers without overloaded names. Later I may think of ways to extend it further but if there's a solution that could work for "all," I would appreciate that the most.

Comment: Doesn't this do what you want? `template<typename R, typename... Args> R apply(R(*f)(Args...), Args... args) { return f(std::forward<Args>(args)...); }` I think I must be missing the point of the question

Comment: where would you use `apply()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's implementation of apply that works with function pointers or callable classes such as lambdas and deduces template parameters:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template<class Fun, class... Args>
typename std::result_of<Fun(Args...)>::type
apply(Fun&& fun, Args&&... args)
{
    return fun(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
```